# How to remove namespace declaration but preserve prefix in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I have an XML with prefix & namespace declaration on some nodes and I would like to remove the declaration but preserve the prefix.

Current XML is showing up as below

```
<Body>  
<n1:ParentNode xmlns:n1="test1" xmlns:n2="test2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <School>
        <n1:SchoolInfo xmlns:n1="test1">
          <SchoolID1>
             <n2:ID xmlns:n2="test2">BAS123</n2:ID>
          <SchoolID1>
        </n1:SchoolInfo>          
     </School>              
</Body>
```

I would like to result to be as below

XML:

```
 <Body>  
<n1:ParentNode xmlns:n1="test1" xmlns:n2="test2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <School>
        <n1:SchoolInfo>
          <SchoolID1>
             <n2:ID>BAS123</n2:ID>
          <SchoolID1>
        </n1:SchoolInfo>          
     </School>              
</Body>
```

What is the easiest way to solve it using XSLT?  Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!!

Comment: Your input  example is missing a closing tags for `n1:ParentNode`  and `SchoolID1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the identity transformation, the superfluous inner namespace declarations will vanish.

I still run (the .NET version) of Saxon 10 (HE) at my site https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/, there, if I run e.g. the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against an input like

```
<Body>  
<n1:ParentNode xmlns:n1="test1" xmlns:n2="test2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <School>
        <n1:SchoolInfo xmlns:n1="test1">
          <SchoolID1>
             <n2:ID xmlns:n2="test2">BAS123</n2:ID>
          </SchoolID1>
        </n1:SchoolInfo>          
     </School>
</n1:ParentNode>
</Body>
```

the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Body>  
<n1:ParentNode xmlns:n1="test1" xmlns:n2="test2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <School>
        <n1:SchoolInfo>
          <SchoolID1>
             <n2:ID>BAS123</n2:ID>
          </SchoolID1>
        </n1:SchoolInfo>          
     </School>
</n1:ParentNode>
</Body>
```

So in my experience the suggestion works with Saxon (10 and others).

Comment: Martin, Thank you for getting back to me. I have used Identity transform and it is returning exactly the same.

Comment: @VijayPullamsetty Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257kSaxon PE-10.6

Comment: @VijayPullamsetty There are 2 possible reasons: (1) You did not implement the suggestion correctly; (2) Your input is different from what you tell us (most likely, the namespace declared at `n2:ID` is different from the one declared at `n1:ParentNode`). Why don't you edit your question and show both your attempted XSLT and a minimal but representative example of the input (the one you show now is not even well-formed XML).

Comment: @VijayPullamsetty, as a Saxon user, if you think the problem is specific to Saxon, here on Stackoverflow you can add the tag for saxon to your question and, a bit like a magical spell, nearly always you will get an answer from Michael Kay itself, the creator of Saxon. But try to explain in detail whether you see the problems when running Saxon 10.6 from the command line or with any Java code and perhaps a particular data/tree model (DOM??). That helps identify the problem or at allow us the make suggestions as to what to change.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinHonnen! I have used 3.0 with mode = on-no-match and it worked. Highly appreciate your help.